# Calculate Average Across Multiple Pairs/Permutations

Tags: excel

Not sure how to use `AVERAGEIFS` or a combination of `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` to efficiently solve this, or some other function.

Basically, assume I have the following dataset of trip times between certain points

```
Start   End   Trip Time(Minutes)

A       B     12
A       B     8
B       A     9
B       A     2
A       C     15
C       A     5
C       B     11
C       B     9
B       C     7
A       B     16
A       D     18
D       C     21
E       A     11
X       Y     19
```

There could be n number of points in the dataset, but assume we are only interested in the average trip time of all trip pairs between 4 cities (A,B,C,D). i.e. AB, BA, AC, CA, BD, DB, etc. but not AA, BB, CC, DD.

How can I go about averaging the trip time between all these permutations? Much help would be appreciated..thank you!

Comment: The average time for all distinct pairs of city (between A and B, between A and c, etc) or for all paths which meet the 4-city criteria.  Do you actually have same-city times (AA, BB, etc) in your list?

Comment: Yes! The average time for all distinct pairs across 4 locations. There may be a handful of same city times. If it's too complex, I don't mind including those as there are so few.

Answer (score 1):

Not very pretty, but using a named range "CITIES" (A20:A23 below)

In E3 to arrange as unique pairs regardless of direction (and fill down):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CITIES,MIN(MATCH(A3,CITIES,0),MATCH(B3,CITIES,0)))&":"&
         INDEX(CITIES,MAX(MATCH(A3,CITIES,0),MATCH(B3,CITIES,0))),"")
```

In F3:

```
=IF(E3<>"",AVERAGEIFS($C$3:$C$16,$E$3:$E$16,E3),"")
```

You can copy/paste values/remove duplicates to get the unique pairs.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526765/folder-creation-on-downloaded-multiple-files-email-or-pdf-from-saptcode-va03

Comment: Tim, this is amazing. Thank you so much!!